# Отличие между перемножением текстур и функцией mix()

Tags: opengl, glsl

Есть фрагментный шейдер:

```
#version 430 core
 
in vec2 texPos;
 
out vec4 color;
 
uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform sampler2D tex2;
 
void main()
{

1-ый вариант
         color = mix(texture(tex, texPos), texture(tex2, texPos) , x); x - какое-то число от 0 до 1
2-ой вариант
         color = texture(tex,out_tex) * texture(tex2,out_tex);
}
```

Я пытался совместить 2 текстуры сначала с помощью первого варианта, а потом с помощью воторого. Я вижу разницу между результатами, но не могу понять что именно происходит при первом варианте, а что при втором.